Datacamp Sample Exam: Python Associate Exam - VoltBike Innovations
I am doing this Pratical exam and when i submit i notice that I have several points that are incorrect and I dont know why.
This is Task 1:
Task1
My implementation is:
import pandas as pd

clean_data = pd.read_csv('ebike_data.csv')

clean_data['bike_type'] = clean_data['bike_type'].fillna('standard') 

clean_data['frame_material'] = clean_data['frame_material'].fillna('unknown') 
clean_data['frame_material'] = clean_data['frame_material'].str.lower() 

clean_data['production_cost'] = clean_data['production_cost'].fillna(clean_data['production_cost'].median()).astype(float)

clean_data['assembly_time'] = clean_data['assembly_time'].fillna(clean_data['assembly_time'].mean()).astype(int)

clean_data['top_speed'] = clean_data['top_speed'].fillna(clean_data['top_speed'].mean()).astype(int)

clean_data['battery_type'] = clean_data['battery_type'].fillna('other') 
clean_data['battery_type'] = clean_data['battery_type'].replace({'-':'other', 'liotherion': 'li-ion'})

clean_data['customer_score'] = clean_data['customer_score'].fillna(clean_data['customer_score'].mean()).clip(lower=1, upper=10).astype(int)

clean_data['motor_power'] = clean_data['motor_power'].str.replace('W','').astype(float)
clean_data['motor_power'] = clean_data['motor_power'].fillna(clean_data['motor_power'].median()).astype(int)

print(clean_data.info())
print(clean_data.isna().sum())


Output:
angeIndex: 2000 entries, 0 to 1999
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------           --------------  -----  
 0   bike_type        2000 non-null   object 
 1   frame_material   2000 non-null   object 
 2   production_cost  2000 non-null   float64
 3   assembly_time    2000 non-null   int64  
 4   top_speed        2000 non-null   int64  
 5   battery_type     2000 non-null   object 
 6   motor_power      2000 non-null   int64  
 7   customer_score   2000 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(1), int64(4), object(3)
memory usage: 125.1+ KB
None
bike_type          0
frame_material     0
production_cost    0
assembly_time      0
top_speed          0
battery_type       0
motor_power        0
customer_score     0
dtype: int64

When i Submit the project this is the feedback I get:
All required data has been created and has the required columns - CHECK
Task 1: Identify and replace missing values - **NOT CHECKED**
Task 1: Convert values between data types - CHECK
Task 1: Clean categorical and text data by manipulating strings - CHECK


Same here bro...

I was stuck on this project as well, but after a couple of attempts, I was able to solve it.
I think what you got wrong is that you forgot to set the data type of the object to categorical. Besides, some parts of your code are different from mine.
My problem was that I was ignoring the instruction at the beginning of Tasks 2 and 3: "You should start with the data in the file 'ebike_data.csv'."
So, for the first question, you should clean the dataset (clean_data), and for Tasks 2 and 3, you should use the data (data = pd.read_csv(...)).
Here's my solution:
# Task 1
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv('ebike_data.csv')
clean_data = data.copy()

# Category Data
clean_data['bike_type'] = clean_data['bike_type'].astype('category')
clean_data['frame_material'] = clean_data['frame_material'].astype('category')
clean_data['frame_material'].replace({'STEel': 'steel'}, inplace=True)
clean_data['battery_type'] = clean_data['battery_type'].astype('category')
clean_data['battery_type'].replace({"-":"other"}, inplace=True)
clean_data['top_speed'].fillna(clean_data['top_speed'].mean().round(2), inplace=True)
clean_data['motor_power'] = clean_data['motor_power'].str.replace('W', '', regex=False)
clean_data['motor_power'] = clean_data['motor_power'].astype('int32')

# Task 2
bike_type_data = data.groupby('bike_type').agg('mean').round(2)
bike_type_data.drop(['top_speed'], inplace=True, axis=1)
bike_type_data.columns = bike_type_data.add_prefix("avg_").columns
bike_type_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
bike_type_data

# Task 3
# clean_data = pd.read_csv('ebike_data.csv')
production_cost_mean = data['production_cost'].mean().round(2)
production_cost_sd = data['production_cost'].std().round(2)
customer_score_mean = data['customer_score'].mean().round(2)
customer_score_sd = data['customer_score'].std().round(2)
corr_coef = data['production_cost'].corr(data['customer_score']).round(2)

bike_analysis = pd.DataFrame({
    'production_cost_mean': [production_cost_mean],
    'production_cost_sd': [production_cost_sd],
    'customer_score_mean': [customer_score_mean],
    'customer_score_sd': [customer_score_sd],
    'corr_coef': [corr_coef]
})

